# При экспорте Календаря Outlook в формате csv нечитаемая кодировка. Как будто их одновременно две. Не получается импортировать в C# через CsvHelper

Tags: c#, кодировка, csv, outlook

**TlDr**: После переустановки Windows из Outlook'a csv экспортируется в нечитаемой кодировке. Файл не грузит в CsvHelper

Экспортирую Календарь Outlook в формате csv через стандартные возможности экспорта Outlook. Открываю его в Notepad++. Файл открывается в кодировке UTF-8 BOM. В этом случае часть текстовых значений отображается нормально, но все заголовки и часть значений в сломанной кодировке[image: CSV в UTF-8]

При смене кодировки на ANSII ситуация меняется. Заголовки начинают отображаться нормально, сломанные данные тоже. Но данные которые корректно отображались в UTF-8 теперь сломаны.
[image: CSV в ANSII]

Ситуация появилась после переустановки Windows. Из того что знаю, я проверил настройки Региона и Локализации, там стоит Русский язык.

В итоге я хочу прочитать этот файл в C#. В данный момент я использую библиотеку *CsvHelper*. Импортирую через маппинг в виде *ClassMap*

```
using var reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<CalendarCSVClassMap>();
var calendars = csv.GetRecords<CalendarCSV>();
```

Попробовал различные настройки Encoding'a для CsvReader'a (кодовые страницы 1251, 1251 и 65001), но результата не дало.

Падает со следующей ошибкой

```
CsvHelper.HeaderValidationException: Header with name 'Тема'[0] was not found.
// ... тут портянка с остальными заголовками
If you are expecting some headers to be missing and want to ignore this validation, set the configuration HeaderValidated to null. You can also change the functionality to do something else, like logging the issue.

IReader state:
   ColumnCount: 0
   CurrentIndex: -1
   HeaderRecord:
["????","???? ??????","????? ??????","???? ??????????","????? ??????????","????? ????","??????????? ???/????","???? ???????????","????? ???????????","??????????? ????????","???????????? ?????????","?????????????? ?????????","??????? ????????","? ??? ?????","????????","?????????","?????","????????","???????","??????????","?????? ??????","???????"]
// .. остальная инфа
at CsvHelper.Configuration.ConfigurationFunctions.HeaderValidated(HeaderValidatedArgs args)
   at CsvHelper.CsvReader.ValidateHeader(Type type)
   at CsvHelper.CsvReader.ValidateHeader[T]()
   at CsvHelper.CsvReader.GetRecords[T]()+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.ToList()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at CalendarDataToAxData.Logic.CalendarCSVReader.ReadActivities(String filePath) in F:\Code\CalendarDataToAxData\CalendarDataToAxData\Logic\CalendarCSVReader.cs:line 39
   at CalendarDataToAxData.Program.Main(String[] args) in F:\Code\CalendarDataToAxData\CalendarDataToAxData\Program.cs:line 45
```

**Вопрос:** Что я могу поменять в коде или в настройке системы. Или как поменять файл, чтобы у меня заработало?
Тестовый csv можно найти тут - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q75jWvInj5oTZopKhYZVEE7ivbU63gcs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Нужно решать проблему с кодировками в системе и аутлуком. Проверьте региональные настройки винды. К вас 2 кодировки в одном файле. Это конечно можно обкостылить, но лучше реально исправить поведение аутлука.

Comment: ANSII - такой кодировки не существует, будьте внимательней. Плюс кодировка ASCII в принципе не поддерживает кириллицу, вы явно что-то перепутали. `Ситуация появилась после переустановки Windows` это ни о чем не говорит, какая была, какая стала, из какого дистрибутива, сборка многоязыковая или русская, слишком много неизвестных.